# How can I make a safe search in Google?

Tags: privacy, google-search

How can I search in a way in Google that prevents my search terms being linked to my identity (cookies, IP ...)? I know there are some tools such as a Firefox extension that makes random searches from time to time to "drown" the real searches among fake ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the 'incognito' mode in chrome, or the 'InPrivate' mode in IE, and then use https://www.google.com to do the search.

This would (somewhat) protect your searches locally, and if you don't log into any google accounts while in incognito mode, it should protect you from having your searches tied to your id in google.

Comment: I just asked the question as an "interesting question" anyway and I meant it to be more related to Google storing my searches (http://www.nytimes.com/2006/08/09/technology/09aol.html?_r=2&oref=login&pagewanted=all) than stuff being on my computer. 
Read "The Problem of Anonymous Vanity Searches" by Christopher Soghoian for more info.

Comment: this does not hide the ip, nor the client (browser), obviously. but if thats a non-issue, this answer is just fine. to hide these kind of information you have to use a "proxy", see tor or other meta-sites (which will then know your ip instead of google knowing it).

Answer (score 3):

use [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/index.html.de) and delete all cookies in your browser after each session.

Answer (score 2):

one option would be something like [Hidemyass](http://www.hidemyass.com/anonymous-search/).

Comment: There is an interesting comment from 'littledave' under http://www.instructables.com/id/Go-Online-without-Getting-Snooped-Tor-The-Onion-/ He makes some good points

Comment: @Miro A.: see my "tor" answer.

Comment: Right. That comment actually belongs to TOR, sorry for misplacement

Comment: then put it there and we delete the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really paranoid, boot a live distro of Linux from CDROM, do the search and switch off the machine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Until yesterday you could have used [Scroogle](http://www.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/scraper.htm), but they're having problems right now.